# c# read nodes from html table

Tags: c#, html

After taking a whole weekend on google and here, without success, I ask for help.
I have this html table:

```html
<TABLE id=tabella width="100%" border=1>
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=55></TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=55>Data</TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=45>Paziente</TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=150>Prestazioni</TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=41>Stato</TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=41>Sede</TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=70>Unità</TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=100>Specialista</TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=41>Contatto (codice,data, n.impegnat.)</TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=15>Stato pag.</TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=20></TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=20></TD>
      <TD class=ListTitle width=20></TD>
    </TR>
    <!-- riga sotto: "title" sostituisce "name" (compatibilità browser) STP 08/05/13 -->
    <TR id=riga_0 title=201503548353>
      <TD class=ListElement>
        <INPUT onclick=selectPatientName(this);abilitaCambiaStato() type=checkbox value="PALMA ROCCO" name=patientSelect>
      </TD>
      <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">
        <CENTER>Giovedi
          <BR>03/12/2015
          <BR>10:45</CENTER>
      </TD>
      <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 11px">
        <B>xxxxx xxxx</B>
        <BR>[xxxxxxxx, 25/05/1965, tel.0000000000]</TD>
      <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">RM COLONNA LOMBOSACRALE</TD>
      <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">
        <CENTER>Eseguito</CENTER>
      </TD>
      <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">11 - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</TD>
      <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx </TD>
      <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">EQUIPE</TD>
      <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">
        <CENTER>PB14310408
          <BR>09/11/2015
          <BR>16015-44444444</CENTER>
      </TD>
      <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">niente</TD>
      <TD class=ListElement>
        <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
          <TBODY>
            <TR>
              <TD>
                <IMG onclick=void(0) title="Appuntamento prenotato" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Appuntamento prenotato" src="Images/app_noconfBW.gif">
              </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD class=Button></TD>
            </TR>
          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
        <BR>
        <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
          <TBODY>
            <TR>
              <TD>
                <IMG onclick="doAppointmentChangeStatus('201503548353')" title="Cambia stato appuntamento" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Cambia stato appuntamento" src="Images/app_status.gif">
              </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD class=Button></TD>
            </TR>
          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
        <BR>
        <IMG alt="" src="Images/empty.gif"> </TD>
      <TD class=ListElement>
        <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
          <TBODY>
            <TR>
              <TD>
                <IMG onclick=void(0) title="Appuntamento non revocabile" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Appuntamento non revocabile" src="Images/iconDeleteBW.gif">
              </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD class=Button></TD>
            </TR>
          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
        <BR>
        <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
          <TBODY>
            <TR>
              <TD>
                <IMG onclick=void(0) title="Appuntamento non spostabile" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Appuntamento non spostabile" src="Images/iconRightArrow_BW.gif">
              </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD class=Button></TD>
            </TR>
          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
        <BR>
        <IMG alt="" src="Images/empty.gif"> </TD>
      <TD class=ListElement>
        <!-- ....LER, 07/06/12 -->
        <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
          <TBODY>
            <TR>
              <TD>
                <IMG onclick="doAppointmentDetails('201503548353')" title="Dettagli appuntamento" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Dettagli appuntamento" src="Images/iconDetails.gif">
              </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD class=Button></TD>
            </TR>
          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
        <BR>
        <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
          <TBODY>
            <TR>
              <TD>
                <IMG onclick="doModificaRichiesta('201503548353')" title="Modifica Richiesta" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Modifica Richiesta" src="Images/ModificaRichiesta.gif">
              </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD class=Button></TD>
            </TR>
          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
        <BR>
        <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
          <TBODY>
            <TR>
              <TD>
                <IMG onclick="doPagaRichiesta('PB14310408')" title="Effettua pagamento" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Effettua pagamento" src="Images/fCash2.gif">
              </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
              <TD class=Button></TD>
            </TR>
          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TD class=ListElement>
      <INPUT onclick=selectPatientName(this);abilitaCambiaStato() type=checkbox value="PAIANO ADDOLORATA" name=patientSelect>
    </TD>
    <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">
      <CENTER>Giovedi
        <BR>03/12/2015
        <BR>11:00</CENTER>
    </TD>
    <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 11px">
      <B>PAIANO ADDOLORATA</B>
      <BR>[MAGLIE, 21/03/1956, tel.0836210592]</TD>
    <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">RM COLONNA LOMBOSACRALE</TD>
    <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">
      <CENTER>Eseguito</CENTER>
    </TD>
    <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">11 - Istituto Santa Chiara - Castrignano dei Greci</TD>
    <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">Istituto S. Chiara RMN - Castrignano de' Greci </TD>
    <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">EQUIPE</TD>
    <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">
      <CENTER>PB14108241
        <BR>28/09/2015
        <BR>16015-0371711463</CENTER>
    </TD>
    <TD class=ListElement style="FONT-SIZE: 12px">niente</TD>
    <TD class=ListElement>
      <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
        <TBODY>
          <TR>
            <TD>
              <IMG onclick=void(0) title="Appuntamento prenotato" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Appuntamento prenotato" src="Images/app_noconfBW.gif">
            </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD class=Button></TD>
          </TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
      <BR>
      <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
        <TBODY>
          <TR>
            <TD>
              <IMG onclick="doAppointmentChangeStatus('201503040650')" title="Cambia stato appuntamento" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Cambia stato appuntamento" src="Images/app_status.gif">
            </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD class=Button></TD>
          </TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
      <BR>
      <IMG alt="" src="Images/empty.gif"> </TD>
    <TD class=ListElement>
      <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
        <TBODY>
          <TR>
            <TD>
              <IMG onclick=void(0) title="Appuntamento non revocabile" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Appuntamento non revocabile" src="Images/iconDeleteBW.gif">
            </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD class=Button></TD>
          </TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
      <BR>
      <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
        <TBODY>
          <TR>
            <TD>
              <IMG onclick=void(0) title="Appuntamento non spostabile" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Appuntamento non spostabile" src="Images/iconRightArrow_BW.gif">
            </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD class=Button></TD>
          </TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
      <BR>
      <IMG alt="" src="Images/empty.gif"> </TD>
    <!-- LER, 07/06/12...faccio diventare la colonna di tipo List element per poter aggiungere altro pulsante -->
    <TD class=ListElement>
      <!-- ....LER, 07/06/12 -->
      <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
        <TBODY>
          <TR>
            <TD>
              <IMG onclick="doAppointmentDetails('201503040650')" title="Dettagli appuntamento" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Dettagli appuntamento" src="Images/iconDetails.gif">
            </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD class=Button></TD>
          </TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
      <BR>
      <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
        <TBODY>
          <TR>
            <TD>
              <IMG onclick="doModificaRichiesta('201503040650')" title="Modifica Richiesta" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Modifica Richiesta" src="Images/ModificaRichiesta.gif">
            </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD class=Button></TD>
          </TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
      <BR>
      <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
        <TBODY>
          <TR>
            <TD>
              <IMG onclick="doPagaRichiesta('PB14108241')" title="Effettua pagamento" class=button style="CURSOR: pointer" alt="Effettua pagamento" src="Images/fCash2.gif">
            </TD>
          </TR>
          <TR>
            <TD class=Button></TD>
          </TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
    </TD>
    </TR>
    <!-- riga sotto: "title" sostituisce "name" (compatibilità browser) STP 08/05/13 -->
    <TR>
      <TD class=Button></TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

And want extract the data nodes.
Most pepole use HtmlAgilityPack and i tried this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection aNodi = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id=tabella]/tbody/tr");
```

Also have tested most parameters in SelectNodes, but return always NULL!
What am i doing wrong?
Thank you all for the help!

Comment: I would suggest you look at this worthy library, [csquery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) which lets you query like jquery in c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select it by id in `SelectNodes` you have to wrap `tabella` in apostrophes:

```
var aNodi = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='tabella']//tbody//tr");
```

You could also use `GetElementbyId`:

```
var aNodi = doc.GetElementbyId("tabella").SelectNodes("//tbody//tr");
```

Comment: Thank you, neither advice works. NullRefernce exception returns. Perhaps the reason may be the first part of my code. I Edit the post and add the first part.
Thank you!

Comment: @Infoservice: i have tried your code and got a `NullRefernceException`. Then i've tried  my approaches and both returned 31 rows. But why do you use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`? Use `doc.LoadHtml(cTabella);`

Comment: I suppose it was wrong the beginning, maybe fatigue, now works all, thank you so much !!!